# Parse:syntax error running angular code inside directives

Tags: angularjs

The following code is giving me `Error: [$parse:syntax]` in console.

```
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav" ng-repeat="webpage in first.webpages">
            <li><a  href ng-click="tab = {{webpage.id}}">{{webpage.name}}</a></li>
          </ul>
```

`ng-repeat` is properly working for `{{webpage.name}}` only, not for `{{webpage.id}}` which is placed inside `ng-click` directive. When I try to print `{{tab}}` nothing shows up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you don't need double braces inside angular elements. And you need to call the parent scope when in ng-repeat :

```
ng-click="$parent.tab = webpage.id"
```

Comment: Alright, you're actually in the wrong scope when using tab in ng-repeat. To get it in your main scope, use $parent.tab.

Comment: thanks, `{{tab}}` works inside the tag with `ng-repeat` only. Why its scope its only under `ng-repeat` only. I am going to use "ng-show="tab === 1" out of `ng-repeat`'s scope, how to do it?

Comment: If you use $parent.tab in your ng-click, you should be able to grab it from outside the ng-repeat with {{tab}}

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav" ng-repeat="webpage in first.webpages">
        <li><a  href ng-click="tab = webpage.id">{{webpage.name}}</a></li>
      </ul>
```

You don't need to interpolate anything when you are inside ng-click since it does it for you.

Comment: Not working, I get `<a href="" ng-click="tab = webpage.id" class="ng-binding">Home</a>` when I inspect the element using Chrome's dev tools. printing {{tab}} also shows nothing.